# Oracle PL/SQL Select into variable using WITH clause

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, select-into, with-clause

I have a WITH clause that gives me the desired result, and i'm trying to put it in a variable. I have omitted code for simplicity. The last line of code is most relevant.

```
WITH ALL_VE_ERRORS AS (

        SELECT *
        FROM ASN.AN_VALIDATION_ERRORS
        WHERE ...

    ), FILTER_STATUS AS (

        SELECT *
        FROM ALL_VE_ERRORS
        WHERE ...

      ) SELECT UNIT_DISCREPANCY FROM FILTER_STATUS INTO W_UNIT_DISCREPANCY; <-- like this
```

But this doesn't work, the compiler doesn't like this. I also tried putting it first like this:

```
SELECT INTO W_UNIT_DISCREPANCY <-- or like this
       WITH ALL_VE_ERRORS AS (...
```

Anyone know the proper syntax to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no reasons I can't see, you don't need two tables in your `WITH` clause; you could simplify it this way:

```
WITH ALL_VE_ERRORS AS (    
    SELECT *
    FROM ASN.AN_VALIDATION_ERRORS
    WHERE ...    
)
SELECT UNIT_DISCREPANCY
INTO W_UNIT_DISCREPANCY
FROM ALL_VE_ERRORS
WHERE ...
```

Otherwise, you can use:

```
WITH ALL_VE_ERRORS AS (    
        SELECT *
        FROM ASN.AN_VALIDATION_ERRORS
        WHERE ...    
    ), FILTER_STATUS AS (    
        SELECT *
        FROM ALL_VE_ERRORS
        WHERE ...    
      )
SELECT UNIT_DISCREPANCY
INTO W_UNIT_DISCREPANCY
FROM FILTER_STATUS
```

Comment: I could, and i know i can do it this way. I've omitted about a 100 lines of code in this one, and while this one is a little bit simpler, we have some with 8 levels of selects that might be 600 lines, which get's really hairy when nesting so i would prefer to find a way to do it with these so i don't have to rewrite this, and for readability, but also for further reference because we have these giant with clauses being used all over my environment. But usually were selecting them into cursors...so maybe i could select it into a cursor, then select the cursor into a variable....

Comment: Ah, im dumb, i put the INTO after the FROM... :)